# to delete previous image in canvas

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in which I draw a picture by clicking a button, then I want to draw another different image by click another button.
The question is how can I delete the previous image of the canvas and load the new image? 
Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

One way to clear the canvas is to draw a rectangle over the whole canvas to remove what was there previously.

```
context.clearRect (0, 0, width, height);
```

Another way is to reset the width of the canvas itself.

```
canvas.width = canvas.width
```

I usually use the `clearrect` method as it simply clears the surface of the canvas whereas the other method resets all sorts of other things like transformations. Also I think I read somewhere that the `clearrect` method is faster, but then again it depends what you want.

As a side point I often find that I don't want to completely clear the canvas but I want to return it to a previous image or a background image. This is most efficiently done by using another canvas as a cache which is not shown on the screen. Then when you want to clear your visible canvas back to a previous state you can just draw the image from the cache using `drawImage`. This is much more efficient than recomputing a set background or previous state.